# inherit css property

Tags: css, html

is it possible to cancel the inherited text-align property in 'no-center' DIV?

Comment: Could you give us an example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean but you can override it with a new value:

```
body { text-align: center; }
div.no-center { text-align: left; }
```